# How to remove CSS classes from the classList of each div element, and assign a desired CSS class to a div element, in an array of div elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, button

I have a set of HTML buttons programmed with JavaScript. There's a class assigned to an array of HTML div elements, and the buttons are supposed to change that class.

Here's the code for one of the buttons:

```
a4.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    //makes sure all the other buttons aren't chosen 

    var button = document.getElementsByClassName('unchosen');
  
    for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) 
    {
      button[i].classList.remove('chosen');
    }
    
    a4.classList.add('chosen');

    //is supposed to assign the new css class to every plate div element and get rid of the undesired classes 

    const plates = document.querySelectorAll(".assay1Plate", ".assay2Plate", ".assay3Plate", ".assay4Plate");

    for (var i = 0; i < 35; i++)
    {  

        
        if (plates[i].classList.contains == "assay1Plate")
        {
            plates[i].classList.remove("assay1Plate");
            console.log("Removed assay 1 plate class due to assay 4 click");
        }
        
        if (plates[i].classList.contains == "assay2Plate")
        {
            plates[i].classList.remove("assay2Plate");
        }
    
        if (plates[i].classList.contains == "assay3Plate")
        {
            plates[i].classList.remove("assay3Plate");
        }

        plates[i].classList.add("assay4Plate");


    //I was going to use this to remove undesired classes from the div elements... but it doesn't really work

    /*

      for(var k = 0; k < classes.length; k++)
      {
          if (plates[i].classList.contains(classes[k]) && classes[k] != "assay4Plate")
          {
              plates[i].classList.remove(classes[k]);
              console.log("Classes removed save 4");
          }
      }

      */
    
    }
});
```

Console.log shows that classes are being ADDED to the classList of the elements, but it doesn't seem like they can be removed once they've already been added. Clicking the first button changes their classes, clicking the second changes it again, clicking the third changes it again, and so on.... but then clicking the first or second buttons again does nothing.

Comment: `setAttribute('class', 'class_to_set');` will remove anything standing previously in the class attribute value and set that new value. It resets and updates the attribute at once. No need to look for class to remove.

Comment: I think the issue might be in that each button click you're running the same loop of removing `.assay[1,2,3]Plate` and then adding the `.assay4Plate` - that doesn't seem to have any individualization - what is that for?